# How to create fulfillments in shopify app (what is wrong with my code?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

Goal: to fulfill orders from shopify app.

**I have the following code:**

**fulfillment controller:**

```
def fulfill_order_2
    order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:order_id) #line 17
    f = ::ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.new(
      # :order_id => reference_number,
      :order_id => order.id,

      :location_id => location_id,
      :tracking_company => tracking_company,
      :tracking_numbers => "1235",
      :line_items => line_items_hash,
    )
    f.prefix_options = { :order_id => reference_number }
    f.save
  end
```

**routes:**

```
get 'fulfillment/fulfill_order_2'
```

**front view:**

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.id %></td>
        <td><%= order.name %></td>
        <td><%= order.total_price %></td>
        <td>
          <% if order.fulfillments.empty? %>
          <%= link_to "Fulfill Order", fulfillment_fulfill_order_2_path(:order_id => order.id, :shop_url => @shop_session.url), :remote => true %>
          <% else %>
            Fulfilled
          <% end %></td>
        <td>
      </tr>
      <%end%>
```

**config scopes:**

```
  config.scope = "read_orders, read_products, write_fulfillments, write_orders"
```

**In my logs, i get:**

`ActiveResource: UnautorizedAccess, Response Code = 401.  Response Message = unauthorized.`

`FATAL line 17` in the method

Question: Is my code completely wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The 401 "UnauthorizedAccess" response indicates you haven't authenticated correctly. You'll need some kind of setup first before you start making privileged requests like retrieving order info.

See [Shopify Authentication](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication) and [the README for the Shopify Ruby Gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) you seem to be using here.

> For a private App you'll need the API_KEY and the PASSWORD otherwise you'll need the API_KEY and SHARED_SECRET.

Comment: I am already able to successfully receive order, collection, and customer information successfully.   The issue is with updating or created fulfillments on the orders.